# Processing XML documentation files prior to Sandcastle

Tags: c#, build-process, sandcastle, xml-documentation

My C# code contains XML comments. During compilation, Visual Studio creates XML documentation files that are then consumed by Sandcastle to create a CHM file.

Now, being lazy, I want to avoid writing XML comments if the information they contain already exists elsewhere. Some of my classes have additional information about their members in the form of custom attributes. So I'm looking for a simple way to automatically add this information to the XML documentation file before Sandcastle processes it.

My idea was to add either a post-build step to the assembly or a pre-build step to the Sandcastle project. Either way, this build step would read the generated XML documentation file into a DOM, do some reflection on the compiled assembly, add this information to the XML DOM, and overwrite the original XML file.

Now I'm wondering:

- Am I reinventing the wheel here? Is there some existing mechanism for adding information to the documentation?
- If my approach is indeed the easiest solution: Is there some existing library that wraps an XML documentation file and allows for easy modification, or is XDocument my best bet? *Note:* I did find [NuDoc](https://github.com/NuDoq/NuDoc), but it seems to be for reading only. I also found the MSDN artible [Processing the XML File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx), so at least the XML file format is documented.